# returning the higher value in logical operators in javascript

Tags: javascript, logical-operators

I am practising the logical operators in JavaScript and fully understood the concepts, but It seems that I didn't with this equation.

```js
    const one = 1;
    const two = 5;
    console.log(one && two);
```

Why in this case it returns five and not one, shouldn't be returned the first value since both are true ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND

Comment: Refer these examples : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND#using_and

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Logical operators in JavaScript — how do you use them?](/questions/4535647/logical-operators-in-javascript-how-do-you-use-them). `&&` evaluates to the first falsy operand or the last truthy operand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [MDN on the && operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND):

> "If `expr1` can be converted to `true`, returns `expr2;` else, returns
> `expr1`."

So in this case, `1` can be converted to `true` (numbers greater than `0` are truthy), so it returns the second value, `5`.

You see this pattern in JSX in React to conditionally render something:

```
{something && <p>render me!</p>}
```

Comment: I can't get this...

Comment: You are correct, after I switched them, it returned the last one. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The LOGICAL && operator returns the last value if all other values are `true`, or else it will return the first non truthy value.

i.e. Java != JavaScript